# Openshift run Proxy server?

Tags: openshift

I've installed my own custom proxy server (written in Java) on Openshift, and run on **$OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP** & port **8080**. The proxy server seems not responding to client request, and the browser always redirect to /app path, eg: www.website.com redirect to www.website.com/app

And then I try to install Squid on local openshift directory account, the squid can run, but give warning about the lack of permission.

Does anyone know how to properly run Proxy Server on Openshift ?